# Iframe url to css div url

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have a url which will showing in iframe

```
<iframe width="250" height="200" frameBorder="0" data-href="http://localhost:8080/webapps/testauth.jsp?appID=a71c5859-03eb-4c16-ac08-1cac24ed2a1d"></iframe>
```

If I paste the above code into any web site, it will showing the widget into the site such as `Facebook plugin`.

But now my job is to change it from the iframe to css div. I don't have too much knowledge of UI part and facing problem can any help me please.

change should be something like this

```
<div class="something"data-href="http://localhost:8080/webapps/auth.jsp?appID=a71c5859-03eb-4c16-ac08-1cac24ed2a1d" data-width="292" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a cross domain ajax request for that. It is done in following steps

- Build the ajax request in a js and put it on the domain from which you want to publish your widget
- Add the script to the page on which you want your widget to appear. Make sure that you set the source of the file to the owner domain and do not copy the js file locally. It is necessary otherwise browser will raise security warning and will not allow it.
- Call the function included js to perform the request and fetch the content from originating domain.

This will make the process of adding the widget a bit more difficult but the div will not allow you to load content from any domain (only iframes and frames can do that).

Comment: Thanks for your response can you please show me some example, or any link

Comment: Just checkout any google api, it works in the same way - google maps

Comment: Sure I can, please brief me out the problem you are facing

Comment: Actually I did not get any link or something which will help me to replace my iframe to something else css or dv

Comment: Idon't know how to call ajax, and how to combine with javascript to solve it as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: What you need to is to go through a simple tutorial for ajax. Later, you just need to put all the js code in a file and host it on your domain to provide the service